# Python Message' object has no attribute 'get_body

Tags: python, imaplib

I'm trying to search email body but facing some issues:

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/python3
from email.message import EmailMessage
import email
import imaplib
import re
import sys
import logging
import base64
import os
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)

###########log in to mailbox########################
user = 'email@company.com'
pwd = 'pwd'

conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("outlook.office365.com")
conn.login(user,pwd)
conn.select("test")
count = conn.select("test")

resp, items = conn.uid("search" ,None, '(OR (FROM "some@email) (FROM "some@email"))')

items = items[0].split()
for emailid in items:
    resp, data = conn.uid("fetch",emailid, "(RFC822)")
    if resp == 'OK':
        email_body = data[0][1]#.decode('utf-8')
        mail = email.message_from_bytes(email_body)

        #get all emails with words "PA1" or "PA2" in subject
        if mail["Subject"].find("PA1") > 0 or mail["Subject"].find("PA2") > 0:
           print (mail)
```

I have issues in following line:

```
body = mail.get_body(preferencelist=('plain', 'html'))
```

getting:

AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'get_body'

Comment: `^M` is likely not `^` + `M`, but another single character: `\r`. Change your regex and try again.

Comment: if you mean this one: `re.sub(r'=(?:\r)?|<br\s*(?:/\s*)?>|[\r\n]+', '', m)` it doesn't work

Comment: You should not update your question to create a new question once you have received answers. Roll back your changes, accept one of the answers (or delete the question if you really have to; but realize that *repeatedly* removing your own question will raise some flags) and ask a new question with full details, and probably a link back to this question for background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not convert the MIME structure to a string and then feed that to `message_from_string`. Instead, keep it as a `bytes` object.

```
from email.policy import default as default_policy
...
items = items[0].split()
for emailid in items:
    resp, data = conn.uid("fetch",emailid, "(RFC822)")
    if resp == 'OK':
        email_blob = data[0][1]
        mail = email.message_from_bytes(email_blob, policy=default_policy)
        if not any(x in mail['subject'] for x in ('PA1', 'PA2')):
            continue
```

You are not showing how you are traversing the MIME structure so I sort of assume you are currently not doing that at all.  Probably you want something like

```
        # continuation for the above code
        body = mail.get_body(preferencelist=('plain', 'html'))
        for lines in body.split('\n'):
            if line.startswith('MACHINE:'):
                result = line[8:].strip()
                break
```

It looks like you have an email body part encoded using `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable`.  The above code is robust against various encodings because the `email` library decodes the encapsulation transparently for you, which gets rid of any QP-escaped line breaks, like the one in your question.  For the record, `quoted-printable` can break up a long line anywhere, including in the middle of the value you are attempting to extract, so you really do want to decode before attempting to extract anything.

Comment: i posted updated code in question and now getting: `AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'get_body'`

Comment: Hang on, the message should be an `EmailMessage` (new style) not a legacy `Message` type.

Comment: Are you sure you are really on Python 3.6?

Comment: Belatedly updated to `import email.policy` as mentioned in @MarkJohnson's answer; dunno how I missed that at the time.

Answer (score 11):

To address the message:

AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'get_body'

When creating the Message object you need to specify a policy or you get the default email.policy.Compat32 policy. get_body() and several other methods did not exist in Python 3.2.

The line creating the mail object should be:

`mail = email.message_from_bytes(data, policy=email.policy.default)`

More information at:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.policy.html

Answer (score 1):

If it's acceptable for you to first remove all the line breaks `=^M\n` from the text, then it's quite simple:

```
import re

email_body = open("1.txt").read().replace("=^M\n", "")

matches = re.findall(r"(?<=MACHINE:)\s*(\w+)", email_body)

print(matches)
print(list(set(matches)))
```

Output:

```
['p1prog07', 'p2prog06', 'p2prog06', 'p1prog07', 'ldnv260']
['p2prog06', 'ldnv260', 'p1prog07']
```

The positive look-behind is a non-capturing group, so the only captured group in the regex is your desired string.

Comment: Better yet, examine the email message's content-transfer-encoding and decode any encoding you see.  This looks like quoted-printable but it could be base64 as well.  The QP encoding could happen in the middle of the value as well.

Comment: no, it doesn't pick all cases: https://regex101.com/r/J17eQ2/3, email_body examples are in link i posted in question:https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AE537%2DgwgAq7iJ0&cid=3803D1529C72EC2C&id=3803D1529C72EC2C%2169650&parId=root&o=OneUp

Comment: @xerks You are right, there is a different line break between `MACHINE` and `ldnmdsbatchxl01`. It would require more insight into how the file is encoded.

Comment: thanks @tripleee, i just posted code for getting email body, not sure how should i decode it ?

Comment: @myrmica, i just posted python code for getting email_body

Comment: The proper way to decode is to use the Python `email` module and read the message with `message_from_bytes` or whatever; the module knows how to decode stuff on the fly.